# What stripe payment charge information should be stored by the application?

Tags: stripe-payments

When integrating stripe payments (or stripe connect), stripe returns a `Stripe::Charge` object to the application after a payment has been attempted.

What is best practice for storing this information, that is, what fields should the application store in its database?

I think at an absolute minimum, the application should store:

- the payment's `id` (so it can be looked up in the future),
- the payment's `status` (so the app can know if the payment went through)
- the app should obviously record which purchase the payment corresponds to

But there are many other fields in the `Stripe::Charge` object which seem quite important. However, storing everything could simply be completely unnecessary (overkill).

Here is an example of a `Stripe::Charge` object returned after a payment intent has been created:

```
{
  "id": "ch_1HwISYGtUKse83O9n9LJ5DK1",
  "object": "charge",
  "amount": 30000,
  "amount_captured": 30000,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee": "fee_1HwISY2fgYVxT5fZTsciNPKg",
  "application_fee_amount": 4500,
  "balance_transaction": "txn_1HwISZGtUKse83O9kkrHTynB",
  "billing_details": {"address":{"city":null,"country":null,"line1":null,"line2":null,"postal_code":"41234","state":null},"email":null,"name":"Ben Johnson","phone":null},
  "calculated_statement_descriptor": "JOE SMITH",
  "captured": true,
  "created": 1607481078,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "description": null,
  "destination": "acct_1HtSLp2fgYVxT5fZ",
  "dispute": null,
  "disputed": false,
  "failure_code": null,
  "failure_message": null,
  "fraud_details": {},
  "invoice": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "on_behalf_of": "acct_1HtSLp2fgYVxT5fZ",
  "order": null,
  "outcome": {"network_status":"approved_by_network","reason":null,"risk_level":"normal","risk_score":63,"seller_message":"Payment complete.","type":"authorized"},
  "paid": true,
  "payment_intent": "pi_1HwIQwGtUKse83O9R4k7NiUa",
  "payment_method": "pm_1HwISXGtUKse83O9ua95HqYJ",
  "payment_method_details": {"card":{"brand":"visa","checks":{"address_line1_check":null,"address_postal_code_check":"pass","cvc_check":"pass"},"country":"US","exp_month":12,"exp_year":2034,"fingerprint":"W0rYzPMfZtx74C5u","funding":"credit","installments":null,"last4":"4242","network":"visa","three_d_secure":null,"wallet":null},"type":"card"},
  "receipt_email": null,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1HYHSFGtUKse83O9/ch_1HwISYGtUKse83O9n9LJ5DK1/rcpt_IXNCchkcmv9fndlQPRCjh4mEtdNtTn0",
  "refunded": false,
  "refunds": {"object":"list","data":[],"has_more":false,"total_count":0,"url":"/v1/charges/ch_1HwISYGtUKse83O9n9LJ5DK1/refunds"},
  "review": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "source_transfer": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "transfer": "tr_1HwISYGtUKse83O9q9ZEE4Gq",
  "transfer_data": {"amount":null,"destination":"acct_1HtSLp2fgYVxT5fZ"},
  "transfer_group": "group_pi_1HwIQwGtUKse83O9R4k7NiUa"
}
```

So the simple, practical question: out of the above info, which fields should be stored in the application's database?

Answer (score 1):

This entirely depends on the needs of your application and there is no universal answer. You can store all of it, none of it, or select fields.

The id is a good place to start, sure. If you were using Customers, you might want to store the associated customer id too. If you were using destination charges, you might want to store the related account. If you wanted to do some custom accounting you might store the amount and the fees.

It depends. Store whatever you like.